# how to config the OneupUploaderBundle?

Tags: symfony, file-upload, jquery-file-upload, oneupuploaderbundle

I am trying to config the OneupUploaderBundle. According to the documentations in 
[github](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md), the given config is:

```
oneup_uploader:
    mappings:
        gallery:
            frontend: blueimp # or any uploader you use in the frontend
```

For this config, I got this error:

```
Twig_Error_Runtime: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "_uploader_upload_gallery" as such route does not exist.") in "MinnAdsBundle:Motors:oneup.html.twig" at line 25.
```

I tried to solve this issue by adding this config (as mentionned in github) to become like this:

```
oneup_uploader:
    mappings:
        gallery:
            frontend: blueimp # or any uploader you use in the frontend  
    resource: .
    type: uploader
```

The obtaind error is:

```
InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized options "resource, type" under "oneup_uploader"
```

So, I am wondering what I have missed in the config of this bundle.

For your information, The version I installed in my symfony project is:

```
"oneup/uploader-bundle": "1.3.1"
```

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation states](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#step-3-configure-the-bundle) the following:

> To enable the dynamic routes, add the following to your routing configuration file.

```
#  app/config/routing.yml

oneup_uploader:
    resource: .
    type: uploader
```

The correct place to put this is not the `config.yml` file but the `routing.yml` file instead.

Comment: Can you tell me what the "enable dynamic routes" option does exactly?

Comment: Sure. Basically it registers a route `/_upload/{mapping}` foreach configured mapping in the router which will be accountable for the file uploads to this mapping. This is not an optional step to do.

Comment: So basically this would be the url you send the uploaded file to ? or am I missing something

Comment: This is correct, yes. Take a look at the implementation of the [`RouteLoader`](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Routing/RouteLoader.php#L32-L53).